# Disable the location (site-chooser) option when asking a question in Stack Overflow for Teams

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions, stack-overflow-for-teams

I would like to request a feature to remove the location (site-chooser) option when asking a question using Stack Overflow for Teams.

[image]

Although it defaults to the team's environment, it would be best if the option to ask the question in the public environment is removed when using the Teams private environment.

Comment: I suppose that is useful in case you have an account as a member of multiple teams...

Comment: FWIW I say no it is not useful or at least it's something that I would like to be able to disable (for similar reasons as why [I'd like to be able to remove or configure search drop-down](/q/417856)). I've never drafted a question in one team and then halfway through decided that I wanted to switch to a different team. Navigation between teams is already easy enough from [the sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7rRB.png).

Comment: I'm not sure removing it would be an improvement, though.  There's a _very_ prominent checkbox that you *must* check to confirm it's a public question in order to post it publicly.

Comment: I believe this UI element is no longer present, with the shift of Teams to its own separate domain. As such, I'm not sure whether to mark this as [status-completed] or close it as no longer reproducible (cc @HenryEcker).

Comment: @V2Blast it looks like you are correct. It's no longer on the main site or in any of the individual teams. I've closed it as no-repro since changes to the system have indeed rendered this obsolete.